# Trailing zeroes should come automatically after/before . (point)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, numbers, number-formatting

I have an input box :

```
<input autocomplete="off"  class='amount'>
```

If i type `.75` in the input field then `0` should be added automatically before `.75` so that it should become `0.75`

Also if i type `1.3` then it should become `1.30`

I have tried :

```
echo "<script>
    $('.amount').on('change', function(){
        $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2));
    });
</script>";
```

**Edited :** its showing me same value what i have typed , no change happening

Comment: So what errors are you getting:

Comment: what output have you got with your script?

Comment: What's the result? How can you type in 3 digits when it has `maxlength='2'`?

Comment: sorry : no result .. blank , i type .75 nothing happen , same for 1.3 nothing happen .. its remain same as its

Comment: @ Tomas  gr8 view .. i have changed that to 3 .. actually i was testing ... and forget to put right one ...

Comment: That's still not enough for number like `1.30`, that's still four characters :)

Comment: It works for me http://jsfiddle.net/4udEJ/

Comment: @ Tomas i remove maxlength :( ... :)

Comment: @ laaposto : dude its working .. but why not working my-side... +1 for jsfiddle help

Comment: any errors in the javascript console of your browser?

Comment: @ Gerald , no error in console..

Comment: try place all your js code into jshint.com and check for any syntax error. it'll tell you if your missing ,'s or ;'s that sometimes console misses.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <?php 
    echo "<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.amount').on('change', function(){
                $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2));
            });
        });
    </script>";
    ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input autocomplete="off"  class='amount'/>
    </body>
</html>
```

You need to make sure to wrap your event handlers in document.ready to make sure jquery is properly loaded before assigning them.  This is why @laaposto 's fiddle works because jquery is already loaded in the fiddle before the event handler is assigned.